# EMC VNX 5300 - How to access Control Station

Tags: command-line-interface, certificate, login, emc-vnx

We have an EMC VNX 5300 and the certificate has expired.  I have already researched the instructions for viewing the certificate and regenerating a new one.  The steps require accessing the Control Station CLI through the service port on one of the SPs using a specific IP address (128.221.1.250).  I have connected with my laptop and am able to use Putty to SSH to the device.  I'm prompted for username and try the only account we have "sysadmin", but I get Access Denied.  I also notice it states "SSH server : Windows Authentication" which leads me to believe it's wanting a domain account but we don't have that setup on the storage (to my knowledge).

The instructions I have specifically say to use the "root" username.  I checked the Global and Local user accounts through Unisphere and only saw the sysadmin account.  So I created the "root" account and tried to login with that but the same results.

Am I doing something wrong, is there another way to access the Control Station CLI?  I've tried SSH to the SP IP addresses and that doesn't work either.  I can't seem to figure out how to get logged in.  Thanks in advance!

Here is a link to the EMC KB article I'm referencing.  It requires an EMC   account to view:  https://support.emc.com/kb/486570

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note:

- That KB article says to login to the control station, which is an entirely different box than the one that uses the ip `128.221.1.250`. The control station is the small box, it has a vga port on the back. I had to use a PS2 keyboard and grub commands to start it in single-user mode to reset the `nasadmin` password.
- The box that DOES use `128.221.1.250` is a Storage Processor (SP). It appears to be running Windows NT Server 6.1.

I was able to login to ssh on the SP of an EMC VNX 5300 and it let me in with

- username: `clariion`
- password: `clariion!`

This begs the question, what do I do next? Posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052905/emc-vnx-5300-storage-processor-shell-management-commands).

Answer (score 0):

It will be the nasadmin account. It's default password is nasadmin